# Sql Row_number and where convert low level speed and how to improve?

Tags: sql-server

I have a 2lakhs data in my table.I want to accessing 40 data only.
Here,Problem is when is fired bellow query

```
    select a.* from 
         (select 
               row_number() over (ORDER BY columnid1) as srno,* 
          from table 
          where 
               columnid1 between 1 and 20 
               and  columnid2 like '%A%'
               and  columnid3 between 20 and 25
         ) as a
        where a.srno>=5200 and a.srno<=5240
```

then it's give result after 12sec.

**How to Improve my Accessing Speed?**

Comment: You have no `order by` in your `row_number()` expression (`(select 1)` is no order). That means that you have no control over what rows you get so you could just rewrite your query to get `top (40)`). That should be faster. Otherwise you should have a look at the execution plan and see if you can do something about your indexes/clustered index. Since you have no `order by` you will most likely get a different resultset if you add an index that will improve performance.

Comment: i MUST USED ORDER BY AND 40 ROWS ONLY NOW WHAT I DO?

Comment: Doing the `...columnid2 like '%A%'..` in your inner query pretty much guarantees it won't be able to use an index on `columid2` - so I don't see how you can speed this up - other than **changing** the search criteria (don't use `LIKE '%....%'` if you want speed)